# ActionScript 3 insert image

Tags: actionscript-3

I need to insert image with original sizes into sprite with fixed width and height. 
Then, I'd like to drag and drop this image.
My code for insert doesn't work.

```
    public class Main extends  Sprite{
public function Main() {
    stage.align=StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
    var loader:Loader = new Loader();
    loader.load(new URLRequest("image.jpg"));
    var sprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
    sprite.graphics.lineStyle(1);
    sprite.graphics.beginFill(0xDDDDDD,0.5);
    sprite.graphics.drawRect(0,0,400,300);
    sprite.graphics.endFill();
    sprite.addChild(loader);
    addChild(sprite);
}
  }
```

Thank!

Comment: "Doesn't work" has a metric ton of reasons why, and a metric ton of variants how. Do you get at least the sprite on screen? Add an `IO_ERROR` event handler to `loader` and watch if it triggers. Add a `Event.COMPLETE` event handler to it and watch if it triggers. And don't cargo code.

Comment: I'm going to take a wild guess: "image.jpg" is not in the same directory as the compiled .swf.

Answer (score 0):

will this work?

```
[Embed(source= "../lib/image.jpg")]
private var Image:Class;

var spriteData:BitmapData = BitmapAsset(new Image()).bitmapData;
var sprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
sprite.graphics.clear();
sprite.graphics.beginBitmapFill(spriteData);
sprite.graphics.drawRect(x, y, width, height);
sprite.graphics.endFill();
addChild(sprite);
```